# New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis on Native test/build

Tags: spring-boot, native, graalvm

I've developed a project using spring-boot, gradlew 8.0.2,  GraalVM CE 22.3.2 native compile.

It works fine till spring-boot 3.0.5, after upgrading to 3.0.6 I got this error during "nativeTest" execution:

```
Fatal error: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis: public it.xxxxxx.reversebox.AppProperties$Osm it.xxxxxx.reversebox.AppProperties.osm()
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.shouldNotReachHere(VMError.java:72)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:696)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis: public it.xxxxxx.reversebox.AppProperties$Osm it.xxxxxx.reversebox.AppProperties.osm()
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.shouldNotReachHere(VMError.java:68)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionFeature.getOrCreateAccessor(ReflectionFeature.java:121)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.target.ExecutableAccessorComputer.transform(ExecutableAccessorComputer.java:43)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.ComputedValueField.computeValue(ComputedValueField.java:343)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.ComputedValueField.readValue(ComputedValueField.java:313)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.meta.ReadableJavaField.readFieldValue(ReadableJavaField.java:38)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.AnalysisConstantReflectionProvider.readValue(AnalysisConstantReflectionProvider.java:97)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.meta.HostedField.readValue(HostedField.java:161)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageHeap.addObjectToImageHeap(NativeImageHeap.java:439)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageHeap.addObject(NativeImageHeap.java:295)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageHeap.processAddObjectWorklist(NativeImageHeap.java:598)

    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageHeap.addTrailingObjects(NativeImageHeap.java:198)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:678)
    ... 4 more
                   36.6s (10.8% of total time) in 56 GCs | Peak RSS: 3.06GB | CPU load: 3.49
```

AppProperties is defined as:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app.xxxxx")
public record AppProperties(String baseUrl, String authUrl, String waybillUrl, String pickupUrl, String clientId,String secretId, String scope, Osm osm) {
  public record Osm(String baseUrl, String url, String xApiKey) {
    }
}
```

Some hint to solve it?

Try to remove inner Osm record but I got similar error on "scope" field

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression caused by some changes in Spring Framework. It will be fixed in Spring Boot 3.0.7 that should be released later this week (at the time of writing) on 18 May 2023. You may like to try `3.0.7-SNAPSHOT` that's available from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot to verify that the fix works for you.

Comment: Thank you. 3.0.7-SNAPSHOT solves the issue. Now I get other runtime errors like: "Runtime reflection is not supported for public void org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.SpringBootMockMvcBuilderCustomizer.setAddFilters" but compile error disappeared.

Comment: That sounds like a Spring Boot bug where it hasn't provided Graal with the information that's required to allow `spring.test.mockmvc.*` configuration properties to be bound. If that sounds like a good fit for what you're trying to do, please open [a Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues). If it doesn't, I'd ask a new question with a minimal, reproducible example.