# Spring + GraalVM throws new method found exception even after running the tracing agent

Tags: spring-boot, native, graalvm

> UPDATE: See the answer for the correct (and much simpler) steps to train and build the native image.

I've been trying to create `Spring Boot native` build steps `without manually adding any configuration`, relying entirely on the `GraalVM Tracing Agent` to discover everything.

It works fine, until I "hide" a manual Jackson ObjectMapper call in the service layer, that relies on reflection.

Then the GraalVM `native-image` build's image creation step breaks and complains about the "hidden" method, that should have been discovered by the tracing agent (see steps 3-5 below).

```
[7/7] Creating image... (0.0s @ 3.14GB)

Fatal error: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis: public java.lang.String com.tlvlp.springnativedemo.AppendRequest.appendWith()
```

I think the problem might be that either the hints for the reflection call are somehow not collected or they don't end up in the right place for the native-image tool to pick it up, but I have run out of ideas to try so I appreciate any guidance.

### Versions:

- `Java 17`
- `GraalVM 22.3.r17`
- `Spring Boot 3.1.0` (should already contain fixes for [a similar issue reported earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263368)).

### Steps to reproduce

[This is the demo project that I was experimenting on.](https://github.com/tlvlp/spring-native-demo) Details are in the README and there the steps + training are triggered by scripts in the project's root.

1. Run a Spring Boot native build to create the initial hints & classes, otherwise the tracing agent will not start. (Would be really nice to eliminate this overhead)

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pnative
```

2. Package the generated hints + classes under `META-INF` into the jar.

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

3. Start the tracing agent to append the existing hints.

```
"$GRAALVM_HOME"/bin/java \
    -Dspring.aot.enabled=true \
    -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir="$(pwd)"/target/classes/META-INF/native-image \
    -jar "$INPUT_JAR_PATH"
```

4. Call the service endpoint to make every internal method call visible for the tracing agent.
5. Stop the tracing agent.
6. Package the generated hints + classes under `META-INF` into the jar.
7. Unpack the jar to a separate folder ([as advised in the Spring Boot native guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.converting-executable-jars.native-image))

```
rm -rf "$NATIVE_BUILD_DIR"
mkdir -p "$NATIVE_BUILD_DIR"
cd "$NATIVE_BUILD_DIR" || exit 1
jar -xvf $INPUT_JAR_WITH_NATIVE_HINTS
```

8. Run the native-image build tool

```
"$GRAALVM_HOME"/bin/native-image \
--no-fallback \
-H:Name=$OUTPUT_EXECUTABLE_NAME \
-cp .:BOOT-INF/classes:`find BOOT-INF/lib | tr '\n' ':'` || exit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is related using "record" for AppendRequest, if you check github issues you will see there were sometimes it was not working [very friendly](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20891) with graalvm, after I convert that to class like below everything worked as expected.

```java
package com.tlvlp.springnativedemo;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AppendRequest {
        @NotEmpty
        String appendWith;
}
```

for tracing I used command below

```bash
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=./src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/ -jar target/native-test.jar
```

for generating the native image used

```bash
mvn -Pnative native:compile
```

for calling the service

```bash
curl -X 'POST'   'http://localhost:8080/append'   -H 'accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{}'
```

response

```bash
{"appended":"START-null"}
```

and server side logs
[image: sb backend logs]

Comment: Haha, thank you, it works! And the training process is much simpler than I thought :)